# Запись цифрового массива в файл

Tags: winapi, c++

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно осуществить запись численного массива в файл. На данном этапе только дошел до записи последнего элемента. (

```
Buffer[i][j] - двумерный массив.

char BufferForWrite[1000]
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        sprintf(BufferForWrite, "%2.1f", Buffer[i][j]);
        k++;
        WriteFile(FileHandle, BufferForWrite, sizeof(BufferForWrite), &memory, &ov);
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас текстовый или бинарный файл?

Comment: @VladD текстовый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем вам WinAPI? Пользуйтесь нормальными высокоуровневыми функциями:

```
std::ofstream f("path/to/file");

if (!f) { /* обработка ошибок */ }

const int M = 3;
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        f << setw(2) << setprecision(1) << Buffer[i][j] << (j == M - 1) ? "\n" : " ";
}
f.close();
```

Comment: Не я же составляю методички с требованиями для выполнения работ. )

Comment: @wao138: Объясните преподавателю, что пользоваться платформо-специфическими функциями при наличии аналогичной функциональности в стандарте — глупость. Если он всё ещё будет требовать писать на голом WinAPI, подумайте об адекватности преподавателя и сделайте соответствующие выводы.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо ) я кое-как сдал эту лабораторную уже)

Comment: С винапи особо не работал, но стало интересно - у него есть что-то совсем специфическое для работы с файлами? Вроде даже для работы с ком-портами используются стандартные fread/fwrite

Comment: @aknew: [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) же!